# Autocomplete not loading correctly - Have to reload page to get it to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am having an issue with this piece of code.  When I initially load my page, the code does not work.  However, if I click on another page on my site and then click on the page again that calls this code, it works perfectly.  I have tried deleting the jquery UI script and that doesn't work.  The issue is with the code that starts with $event_name and calls the autocomplete jquery routine.  If I comment that code out, the page loads correctly.  If I put the code back in, I have to then load another page first before loading this page.

All suggestions are welcome.  Thanks Grant

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#artist_create_event_desc').jqEasyCounter({
        'maxChars': 500,
        'maxCharsWarning': 1,
        'msgFontSize': '12px',
        'msgFontColor': '#000',
        'msgFontFamily': 'Verdana',
        'msgTextAlign': 'left',
        'msgWarningColor': '#F00',
        'msgAppendMethod': 'insertAfter'                
    });
});
    $event_name = $('#name');
    $event_address_container = $('#address-container');
    $event_id = $('#id');
    $event_name.autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source: '../search_event.php',
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $event_name.val( ui.item.event_name );
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $event_name.val( ui.item.event_name );
            $event_id.val( ui.item.event_id );
            $event_address_container.html( ui.item.event_desc );            

            return false;
        }
    })
    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.event_desc + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };

$('#searchme').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#city').val('');
    jQuery('#state').val('');
    jQuery('#location').val('');
    jQuery('#hiddenstate').val('');
    $('#aloader').show();
    var varzip = $('#zipcode').val();
    if (varzip == '') {
        $('#aloader').hide();
        alert('Please enter zipcode');
        return;
    }
    varzipReplaced = varzip.split(' ').join('+');
    $.ajax({
        url : 'location.php',
        data : 'zip='+encodeURIComponent(varzipReplaced),
        type : 'post',
        success : function(res) {
            $('#aloader').hide();
            var dataObj = $.parseJSON(res);
            if (dataObj.city == '' && dataObj.state == '' && dataObj.country == '') {
                $('#city').removeAttr("readonly");
                $('#state').removeAttr("readonly");
                $('#location').removeAttr("readonly");
                alert('No location found! Enter information manually');
                return;
            } else {
                $('.showZipErr').empty().append('<strong>*Zipcode*:</strong>');
                if (dataObj.city != '') {
                    $('.showCityErr').empty().append('<strong>*City*:</strong>');
                    $('#city').val(dataObj.city);
                } else {
                    $('#city').removeAttr("readonly");
                }
                if (dataObj.state != '') {
                    $('.showStateErr').empty().append('<strong>*State or Province*:</strong>');
                    $('#state').val(dataObj.state);
                } else {
                    $('#state').removeAttr("readonly");
                }

                var stateWithShortName = dataObj.stateshort + "-" +dataObj.state
                if (dataObj.state != '') {
                    $('#hiddenstate').val(stateWithShortName);
                } else {
                    $('#state').removeAttr("readonly");
                }

                if (dataObj.country != '') {
                    $('.showCountryErr').empty().append('<strong>*Country Code*:</strong>');
                    $('#location').val(dataObj.country);
                } else {
                    $('#location').removeAttr("readonly");
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Error fetching location');
        }
    });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: If possible, can post `html` ? Thanks

Comment: I tried posting the code by Stackoverflow says over by 5,000 characters.  Just the form alone.  Most of the html is just Div's and a form.

Comment: Can try portion which includes `#name` ?

Comment: Here is the code that references the #name         
<label class="label">Venue Name:</label>
         <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
         <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Venue Name">
         <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Venue Name to create an Event</b> </label>
<input type="reset" class="submit_event_button" value="<?php echo 'clear name search' ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" />
<strong><p id="address-container"></p></strong>

Comment: Note, Not tried `jsEasyCounter` , can include expected return object/values from `search_event.php` jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/80emnapd/

Comment: I deleted all the code relating to the jsEasyCounter including the JS script and still did not work.  the autocomplete code everything works great, but something with the autocomplete forces me to refresh the page each time to get it to work.